# Upgraded to .NET 8: DbContext is null

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I upgraded my Razor pages app from .NET 7 to .NET 8. The app was working fine in .NET 7. In .NET 8, the `DbContext` is null.

Relevant pieces in my app:

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Eigenaar> Eigenarens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Object> Objectens { get; set; }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StallingRazor.Data;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
  //  options.RootDirectory = "/Stalling2";
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Eigenaren/Index", "");
});
builder.Services.AddSession();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
));
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Index.cshtml:

```
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public EigenarenModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public IEnumerable<Model.Eigenaar> Eigenaren { get; set; }
```

And this is the error:

[image: Text]

Any hint on why this worked in .NET 7 and does not work in .NET 8 is appreciated.

Edit: Added the csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JW.Pager" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.59.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore" Version="23.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="TinyMCE" Version="6.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="toastr" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Maybe some dependencies have not been properly updated

Comment: Have you added the `EigenarenModel` as a dependency in the `program.cs` class?

Comment: @IceCode: I did not add this model in Program.cs. Is that a requirement of .Net 8?

Comment: @ErikEj: Relevant part of csproj added in the OP.

Comment: Just wondering when the `ApplicationDbContext` is registered in the `program.cs` file and then passed to the `EigenarenModel`.. I would suggest you tried to add the `EigenarenModel` as a dependency and see if the `ApplicationDbContext` still is `null`.

Comment: @IceCode: Intellisense does not accept a using statement for the Model in Program.cs. Added start of the Model in the OP and edited the use of it in Index.cshtml.

Comment: @leof were you able to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Not yet, but I now got the inner problem: "An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created." Not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: The only way to resolve this problem is probably to make use of services, register them and use Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

I created a .NET 7 project with DbContext for testing. I used the [Upgrade Assistant](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant) to update it from .NET 7 to .NET 8, and it worked fine for me. I think your error might be caused by having the wrong versions of dependencies. Perhaps you could try re-updating using this tool.

If this approach doesn't work, it typically points to the location of the error. You could then provide the error information for further assistance.

Comment: No difference when using the Upgrade Assistent. Exact the same error messages:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
When further digging: "An attempt was made to use the model while it was being created. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any way that makes use of the model that is being created."

Comment: how about create a demo to test if the same issue persists,  If the problem still occurs, look the difference between the config?

Comment: What I sofar discovered is that my app works when I only use one Model in de dbcontext. As soon as I add a second one, the error pops up.